# How upload docx, pdf file with renaming?

Tags: php, pdf, file-upload, doc

Hi i create a coding to upload docx file and pdf file. Following are the coding for this.

```
$allowedExts = array("pdf", "docx");//array("mp4", "WebM", "ogg");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if (($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 90000000000000000000000000000000000) && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)){
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0){
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }else{
        echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
        echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
        echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
        echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";
        if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])){
            echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
        }else{
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
            "docmument_upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
            echo "Stored in: " . "docmument_upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        }
    }
```

But i want rename the file before upload to folder. How can i do this?

Comment: who is 'you'? you as a programmer in the code or you as the user uploading the file? always or only when duplicate is found? anything happens if the new name exists but the old one don't?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you  get the file extension using

```
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension= end($temp);// file extension
```

Rename your file name as

```
$new_name=time().".".$extension;// new name with current timestamp
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"docmument_upload/" .  $new_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your line of code

From

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
            "docmument_upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

To

```
$newFileName="newName".".".$extension;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
            "docmument_upload/" . $newFileName);
```

$newFileName is the variable where you can create your new file name. Always care for overwriting issue , so try to make file name unique .

$extension is the variable what you are using to validate.

Answer (score 0):

This will produce the desired results for you:

```
$ext = end((explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"])));
$filename = time(). rand(). "." . $ext;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "docmument_upload/" . $filename);
```